# SPARK_CONF not found in AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am trying to deploy a spark application in EMR and facing the following issue.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://ip-10-184-176-172.ec2.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1446113189622_0004/__spark_conf__2712437380309904293.zip
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:357)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am deploying in cluster mode using the emr console UI. In the first line it specifies the SPARK_CONF zip is uploaded in the hdfs location but the error says file not found on the same location. have anyone faced similar issue?

Answer (score 4):

Issue Resolved. I was using unsupported JAVA version. EMR has java 7 and my application was developed in java 8.